# Apache2 on Docker with files on volume mount not rendering but downloading

Tags: docker, apache, httpd.conf, docker-volume

Anyone has seen this issue, httpd on docker will render local htdocs files correctly. But if I mount htdocs as volume / persisted volume, it downloads files (text, images, htmls ) instead of rendering.

I tried this configuration too, but didn't work:
`<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"> EnableSendfile On </Directory>`

More info as requested in comment:
If the contents of /usr/local/apache2/htdocs are from volume mount (pvc on k8s ) including index.html. Hitting index.html actually downloads files instead od rendering.

If the contents of /usr/local/apache2/htdocs are from not from volume mount, but just copied locally, index.html ( or any files ) will get rendered properly.

Please help!

Thansk,

Comment: Please share more details, like a better explanation of your problem, the configuration of your containers, and how this is related to programming

Answer (score 0):

it started working  this this config on. "Allow from All"

<Directory "/var/www/html/sites/default/files">
EnableSendfile On
Allow from All

thanks,